# how to set OnEditorActionListener

Tags: android

```
    EditText lastedit = new EditText(this);
    lastedit.setHint("Last name");
    blur.addView(lastedit);
    MarginLayoutParams params22 = (MarginLayoutParams) lastedit.getLayoutParams();
    params22.width = 460; params22.leftMargin = 16; params22.topMargin = 265;
    lastedit.setLayoutParams(params22);
    Typeface font22=Typeface.SERIF;
    lastedit.setTypeface(font22);
    lastedit.setMaxLines(1);
    lastedit.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
```

here i want that when i press enter it will automatically go to next field. I attact 4 edit text view in my code dynamically like above and then finally automatically button will press and go to next activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `setInputType` for EditText. It will solve your problem.

Comment: thanx a lot it work :-) one more thing one.how button will hight light   when i press enter on last edit field.

Comment: You can override onkeypress on your edittext and check if the enter was pressed and if true then
    `myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) { 
              // highlight Button Code
   
        }
    }
});`